# extract value from header returned in axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I need to get a cookie value which is returned in the header from my axios post request. So, I make a request to the server and I get a response like this by logging the data to the console. If I console.log `data.headers.server` all I get back is 'Apache'.

```
console.log(data.headers);
```

The response:

```
{
  date: 'Tue, 11 Aug 2020 17:52:59',
  server: 'Apache',
  'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
  'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
  'content-length': '85',
  'set-cookie': [
    'ASP.NET_SessionId=12tz7bfonzkqaywiepwynvm3; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax'
  ],
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  connection: 'close'
}
```

I need to get the set-cookie value ie: ASP.NET_SessionId....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also access a property of an object this way:

```
data.headers['set-cookie'];
```

Then you will need to access the first element, since it is an array:

```
data.headers['set-cookie'][0];
```

```js
let data = {
  date: 'Tue, 11 Aug 2020 17:52:59',
  server: 'Apache',
  'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
  'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
  'content-length': '85',
  'set-cookie': [
    'ASP.NET_SessionId=12tz7bfonzkqaywiepwynvm3; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax'
  ],
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  connection: 'close'
}

console.log(data['set-cookie'][0]);
```

In general:

```
object.prop
//is equivalent to
object["prop"]
```